# Node.js csv-parse error mystery using Sails

Tags: node.js, csv, sails.js

It processes most of the records from the .csv file. However, at the end I get this error with csv-parse node module and can't figure out why. It terminates my server so I need to resolve it. Please help

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Number of columns on line 37052 does not match header
    at Error (native)
    at Parser.__push (/Users/Development/apps/SailsJS/my-project/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:222:13)
    at Parser._flush (/Users/Development/apps/SailsJS/my-project/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:189:12)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (_stream_transform.js:118:12)
    at Parser.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at prefinish (_stream_writable.js:504:12)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:512:7)
    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:524:3)
    at Parser.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:489:5)
    at ReadStream.onend (_stream_readable.js:511:10)
    at ReadStream.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

My Controller API

```
upload: function(req, res){

    req.file('statData').upload(function(error, files){

        var fs = require('fs'); 
        var parse = require('csv-parse');

        var csvData=[];
        var lines = 0; 

        var filePath = sails.config.appPath + '/data/file.csv'; 


        fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            .pipe(parse({
                columns: false,
                delimiter: '\t', 
                 skip_empty_lines: true,
                 relax: true
            }))
            .on('data', function(csvrow) {

                csvData.push(csvrow);                        

            })
            .on('end',function() {
              //do something wiht csvData 
            });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using fast-csv module and worked.